# Create a custom cursor with mousemove event in a jLabel

Tags: java

Please help my problem. When lblCur Entering lblBnt, Mousemouse event does not work correctly. It looks like lagging, poor FPS or something like this.

If I remove lblBtn.addMouseListener(...),  lblBg.addMouseMotionListener(...) working fine!. But I cant get Event when I click in lblBnt...

Code: http://pastebin.com/ZBJySGEq

```
public myjFrame()
    {
        setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(new ImageIcon(UrlImg("cur_empty.png")).getImage(),new Point(0,0),"cursor_default"));
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        lblBg= new JLabel();
        lblBg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(UrlImg("main_menu_bg.png")));
        lblBg.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                cMouseDragged(evt);
            }
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                cMouseMoved(evt);
            }
        });
        this.add(lblBg);
    lblBg.setLayout(null);`

        lblBtn= new JLabel();
        lblBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(UrlImg("choi.png")));
        lblBtn.setBounds(120, 310, 345, 132);
        lblBtn.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lblChoiMouseClicked(evt);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lblChoiMouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                lblChoiMouseExited(evt);
            }
        });  
        lblBg.add(lblBtn);
        lblCur= new JLabel();
        lblCur.setIcon(new ImageIcon(UrlImg("cur_def.png")));
        lblCur.setBounds(200, 200, 155, 155);
        lblCur.setText("");
        lblBg.add(lblCur);
    }
    private void cMouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        lblBg.add(lblBtn);
        lblCur.setLocation(evt.getX()-40,evt.getY()-40); 
    }
    private void cMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        lblCur.setLocation(evt.getX()-40,evt.getY()-40);
    } 
     private void lblChoiMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
      lblBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(UrlImg("choi_hover.png")));
    }                                    

    private void lblChoiMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
         lblBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(UrlImg("choi.png"))); 
    } 
     private void lblChoiMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        this.dispose();
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myjFrame main= new myjFrame();
        main.setBounds(100, 100, 769,892);
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw0by9qPYJ8TTWoydGtGbHZMbU0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you rendering ? After reading through your code I couldnt find a repaint()

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem in the forum, not on an external website.

Comment: Please post suspect code within the site here rather than a link elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

In your `MouseListener` you can use:

```
event.getComponent().setCursor();
```

Read the Cursor API for more information. You can use the `getPredefinedCursor()` method.

The `mousePressed()` method would set the cursor. Then in the `mouseReleased()` method you would set the cursor to null to restore the default cursor.

**custom cursor**

Cursor custom = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(...);
and you provide the image to use for the Cursor.

Comment: Thanks bro, but if I use Cursor, this will make my cursor 32x32. So, I must use lblCur like a Cursor  ` lblCur.setLocation(evt.getX()-40,evt.getY()-40); `